# How to run custom MongoDB commands in ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to convert the following MongoDB command into ReactiveMongo format:

```
db.changeUserPassword("user", "password")
```

There is a lot of documentation on running aggregate queries and sorting your data after running a simple command such as match, count etc.

Commands such as:

```
db.collection.insert()
```

Are easy to use in ReactiveMongo, but is there a specific way to convert more complicated commands such as:

```
db.grantRolesToUser()
db.createRole()
```

into ReactiveMongo commands?

Comment: Why such setup/configuration aren't done outside/before Scala app?

Comment: It would be nice if these options were also available in the Reactive Mongo API, seeing as you can add users and rename collections using the API. We were looking into administrating our Mongo database entirely through an Akka service but it looks like we will need to do these jobs through Mongo instead.

Comment: I generally recommand to setup the DB outside the app. It could have value if you want to develop an app whose main goal is to admin DB.

Comment: We will have to do that, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DBMetaCommands`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.DBMetaCommands) trait is the ReactiveMongo API that comes the closest to what you're looking for. With this API, one can, for example, [create](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.DBMetaCommands@createUser(name:String,pwd:Option[String],roles:List[reactivemongo.api.commands.UserRole],digestPassword:Boolean,writeConcern:reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern,customData:Option[reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument])(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]) a user with a password and roles, but I don't think there's a ReactiveMongo API that enables one to update an existing user or create a role.

Comment: Thank you. This could work if there was also a delete user command in the API, then I could first delete the user then create a new user with the new password. Too bad the documentation is not very clear.

Comment: All DB ops provided as functions are documented: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB@MetaCommands.html